# Conditional Display

Tags: sql

i have an "active" field in the database that has the words "active" and "inactive" in it

how can i do i select, to only show Y and N, depending on the "active"/"inactive" wording in that field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT....
CASE WHEN Active = 'Active' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
....
FROM Table
```